# how to create a session with a proxy server

Tags: windows, scripting, proxy

I have the following problem. I have an application (3rd party) that needs to connect to API via a proxy to request various data again and again. The application has a configuration section where the necessary details can be entered (the app then stores them in a config.ini file). However, one client doesn't like the proxy user/password to be stored in config files;

As I don't have access to the application's code, the simplest solution I can think of is something along the lines of a tunnel, i.e. write a simple app/script that would open a connection to the proxy, prompts the user for the username/password and then keep the connection open so that the application can access the proxy without needing username/password everytime. Is something like this possible? I mean I don't to create sort of full blown proxy that would sit between the app and the real proxy server, all I really want is something like a session so that once the IP is authorized to get through the proxy, the consequent requests go through as well.

I'd appreciate help and/or any suggestions for an alternate solution

p.s. the app is win32 only so the solution is for win32 only as well (ie no cygwin, etc.)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy credential caching typically works on a per-process basis, not a per-machine basis. So, having Application A make a request through the proxy rarely allows Application B to make a request without getting challenged.

If you can change the application's code, make a single request through the proxy using the desired credentials; e.g. make a HEAD request for your server's homepage. Most HTTP stacks (e.g. WinINET) will cache the proxy credentials for the life of the process.